# How do I search relations on tables SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables like this
[image]

With the tables filled like this:
[image]

How do I search the cases In where on the table 3 the idtable 1 has all the id from table 2 related? 
For example idtable1 = 1 would be an output of that query cuz is related with every id from idtable2

Comment: I don't understand.  What does table 2 have to do with this question?

Comment: Post some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: It seems that Table 3 is a *link* table between 1 and 2.

Comment: Table 3 is already filled with data. For example Table 3 row1: idtable1 =1 / idtable2 =1, row 2 idtable1 =1 / idtable2 = 2, row 3 idtable1 =1 / idtable2 = 3

Comment: [Edit] your question and add some sample data for all three tables and the desired result.

Comment: I had already edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you intend:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where (select count(*) from table3 t3 where t3.idtable1 = t1.idtable1) =
      (select count(*) from table2);
```

This shows all records from `table1` where `table3` contains all values of `idtable2` -- assuming no duplicates in `table3` (and that the ids are unique).

Comment: I edited the question, please take a look so you could understand it better

Comment: @LuisFernandoBadelMéndez . . . I think this does what you want.

Comment: What is the output of your code suposed to be? Because in my real database it doesnt show me anything